# Docker DELETE commands gets executed every half hour

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm new to docker and was going through docker logs and found DELETE command being executed every half an hour

```
time="2017-10-09T09:36:39.757830525Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.17/images/sha256:69522f5b2cfaf11703b4911fe40c2dc8e1f1469ab756910f0cf679e2b1db1960 returned error: conflict: unable to delete 69522f5b2cfa (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container f7142fd07c44"


time="2017-10-09T10:06:39.758068930Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.17/images/sha256:69522f5b2cfaf11703b4911fe40c2dc8e1f1469ab756910f0cf679e2b1db1960 returned error: conflict: unable to delete 69522f5b2cfa (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container f7142fd07c44"


time="2017-10-09T10:36:39.757730005Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.17/images/sha256:69522f5b2cfaf11703b4911fe40c2dc8e1f1469ab756910f0cf679e2b1db1960 returned error: conflict: unable to delete 69522f5b2cfa (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container f7142fd07c44"


time="2017-10-09T11:06:39.757938287Z" level=error msg="Handler for DELETE /v1.17/images/sha256:69522f5b2cfaf11703b4911fe40c2dc8e1f1469ab756910f0cf679e2b1db1960 returned error: conflict: unable to delete 69522f5b2cfa (must be forced) - image is being used by stopped container f7142fd07c44"
```

Any Idea why DELETE command is being executed repeatedly? How do i debug it?

Comment: Where did you find these log messages?

Comment: We use Amazon ECS Optimized image ( ami-cf03d2ac ). For log we check  "vi /var/log/docker"

Comment: This is a bit like looking at your webserver logs and wondering why someone keeps hitting a random page on your site. You'll need to look at any scripts or automation that has access to your docker API.

Comment: @BMitch : There is no automation, no jobs, no scripts from our end. Is there any other log file that I should check??

Comment: If there's nothing else running with access to your docker API that you know of, then it's something you don't know of with access to your API. Maybe you've been hacked, or maybe it's some ECS automation that you're ignoring. Docker doesn't log the source of the connection so there's nothing to further debug from here.

Comment: Finally I figured it out. It was due to AWS automated task and Image clean up (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/automated_image_cleanup.html) . By default ECS_DISABLE_IMAGE_CLEANUP is set to false.